# Papal Blessing at World Youth Day 2016

Tags: catholicism, papacy, blessings

A friend of mine will be attending [World Youth Day 2016](https://register.wyd.va/Welcome/?lang=en) in Krakow, Poland from July 26 - August 1.

He will be carrying some religious medals with him to be blessed by Pope Francis. He is under the impression that if one holds up any religious objects during the closing blessing of the Papal Mass that these medals would be considered as being blessed by the Holy Father.

I have not heard of such a tradition or manner of obtaining a Papal Blessing for religious objects.

Can anyone confirm one way or another if such a blessing on medals is at all considered Papal or not?

Comment: Not authoritative, but we did do that at WYD in Colonge in 2005.  I remember there was a point in time when we were made aware that Pope Benedict was going to bless us, and at that point, we'd hold up our things we wanted blessed by the Pope.   Shoot, now you made me really wish I hadn't lost that rosary!

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, the Holy Father does bless rosaries and other items such as medals at the conclusion of Papal Audiences, the Sunday Angelus, and Papal Masses!

The following is taken from [The Pontifical North American College:](https://www.pnac.org/visitorsoffice/faq/)

> At the conclusion of Papal Audiences, the Sunday Angelus, and Papal Masses, the Holy Father gives his Apostolic Blessing. This blessing is for you, your family, your loved ones, and any items for devotional use that you have brought with you to be blessed. Items such as rosaries, crucifixes, holy cards, or medals simply have to be with you to be blessed. The Holy Father has the intention of blessing these articles.

Outside of special papal events such as World Youth Day how can one obtain a rosary or medal blessed by the Pope when one can not be present in Rome?

> So what do you do if you want to get a rosary blessed by the pope but can't get to Rome?  Anything but buy one already blessed.  The best thing to do is talk to a priest or vowed religious you know.  Chances are he/she can connect you with someone who is going to Rome or who is currently studying or working there.  That person can take your item or obtain one there for you, get it blessed by the pope, and get it back to you.  People who travel to Rome are asked to do this all the time.  Another option is contacting one of the reputable gift shops in Rome. A decent store near the Vatican will sell you the item, then take it to the next General Audience and have it blessed for no additional charge. - [From the Back of the Church](http://fromthebackofthechurch.blogspot.ca/2013/03/simony-or-scam-need-rosary-blessed-by.html)